# How to handle authorization that is dependent on the requested data

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, asp.net-core, architecture

I have an API project that has a lot of access restrictions depending on the item the user is requesting. For example, let's say I have an Action like this:

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditItem([FromBody]Item editedItem)
{
    var item = await db.Items.SingleOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == editedItem.Id);

    if (item == null) // There is already pre-filter on the DB.
        return Unauthorized();

    if (item.Status == ItemStatus.Closed)
        return Unauthorized();

    if (item.Owner != _currentUser)
        return Unauthorized();

    // Say the normal user only have permissions to edit items on the Status "Added"
    if (!(_currentUser is Manager) && editedItem.Status == item.Status.Open)
        return Unauthorized();

    // Edit the data...

    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok();
}
```

The software is growing and this is starting to get noisy and not clean. The actions have 90% of permission checks and 10% of actual code.

In every controller I have lots and lots of checks for permissions. I am already using Authentication and Authorization; that is not the case. Here, it depends on the Item that the user is requesting access.

What I want to do is remove the checks from the controller and reduce complexity of the code.

I already tried to create custom polices, custom attributes and a custom middleware, but checking the database two times is a lot slower and it did little to reduce complexity.

Are there any guidelines regarding this kind of problem that I am missing?

Comment: How about an `IActionFilter`, for example an extension of the `AuthorizeAttribute`. You can even register ActionFilters globaly.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest making some kind of authorization service which would handle everything you need. For example:

```
public class AuthorizationService
{
    ...

    public Task<bool> IsAuthorizedAsync(Item item)
    {
        var authorized = item != null 
                            && item.Status != ItemStatus.Closed 
                            && item.Owner == _currentUser 
                            && (!(_currentUser is Manager) && editedItem.Status == item.Status.Open);
        return Task.FromResult(authorized);
    }
}
```

Of course you could add other methods for authorization which would be doing checks over some other entities (not only Item).

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you have 5 types of user role. Each Role have it's own view based on set of rules.

Now consider that, you have 20 Functionality.
User 'Role Type 1 'will get many of the functionality but not everything. So once you are creating your functionality you need to make them simple responsible, unique and individual.

Consider this image for your visualization :

[image: Apply access of each type user role according the set of rules]

The pseudo could be like this:

1. Check the logged in user role type
2. Get permitted ID of each feature or functionality list based on the user role type
3. Load the feature or functionality of that user

Note: There could be a common Feature list which is applicable for all type user.

Answer (score 1):

you have two ways to check permissions, first is app side (controller is not good choice it would be good if you have helper or BaseController at least). you could try overriding OnActionExecuting in your base controller and check permissions there

and second:

if you are using Mssql database or similar this you can check permissions in database side (create function or stored procedure) which returns 0 or 1 (0 means user doesn't have permission)

Answer (score 1):

- Controllers' action should have straightforward happy-pass logic.
- Any `permission checks/validations` logic based on request parameters should be decoupled by using [middlewares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware)/[filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters).
- If validation checks don't depend on request parameters, then it is better to move logic to dependency services and raise an exception to stop further request execution.
- And Exception handling should be decoupled by using middlewares/filters.

---

> but checking the database two times is a lot slower

You can store data from first database call (let's say in middleware) in `HttpContext.Items` and then in action just get that data from context instead of database again.

> `HttpContext.Items`: Gets or sets a key/value collection that can be used to share data within the scope of this request.